# How long does it take to learn algebra?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, self-learning

I've searched through this site but couldnt find a question like this, so i'm asking: How long does it take to learn algebra 1 and 2? I have 5 hours to dedicate to math per day. I know pre-algebra and now im studying Rational Expressions so you can guess my level of algebra, i'm in the beginning. Is it possible to learn algebra until the end of this year?

Obs: I'm studying by myself. I want to go to college by the next year (feeling a bit old btw but that is another story)

Many thanks for all who answer, God bless you all.

Comment: Algebra I doesn't take long; it's pretty basic. Algebra II takes a little more time, and it requires a little bit of Geometry along with it. You could definitely teach Algebra I to yourself in under a year, but Algebra II will take a while.

Comment: You can learn it as fast as you can watch the tutorials on you tube, it shouldn't take longer than 1 month to complete all the algebra you need for college. Do you have a listing of topics?

Comment: what are the topics of algebra I and algebra II in your country?

Comment: Are you looking to know everything up to calculus by the time you hit college? My high school took 5 terms to get me there. You could do it much faster if you're interested in the content.

Comment: Yes, basically I want to learn: Equations and Inequalities/ Coordinates and Graphs/ Functions/ Polynomial and Rational Functions/ Exponential and Logarithimic Functions/ Analytic Trigonometry/ Polar Coordinates and Vectors/ Systems of Equations and Inequalities/ Analytic Geometry/ Sequencies and Series/ Counting and Probability. I took this from the book: Algebra and Trigonometry by James Stwart. If you can help I'd be glad to hear suggestions.

Comment: Yes, I want to learn everything up to calculus if its possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll be honest, it doesn't take that long. Do you have good fundamentals? Can you understand expressions and simplification? Those are practically the keys to understand Algebra I, geometry, and Algebra II.  Everything in the first three classes (Algebra I, geometry, and Algebra II) is a lot of memorization until you begin to understand things. Then, it gets easier once you have the intuition to do this.

It seems like you also want to learn Precalculus as well. After you learn these, I would suggest you also look into the beginning of Precalculus while simultaneously exploring the basics of competition math. This will help you learn the applications/connections between the earlier levels, Precal, and the real world.

If you want to learn calculus, it won't be too difficult if, like I said earlier, you get the intuition. I'm not taking calculus right now (I'm in precal, but I taught myself calculus because it was fun) but online resources make it really easy to learn.

If your schedule is completely free, then I think it is possible to learn everything (Algebra I to Calculus) in one year. Also, in regards to resources Khan Academy may seem boring, but it works. There's a huge amount of practice problems that you can do, and the videos/communities are great if you have no idea what's going on. Obviously, there's also StackExchange :).

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, learning math means a lot to me (although I'm noobie I like it and I can see the value of it in the real world. I'm learning Rational Expressions and Factoring Polynomials, I know most of the stuff up to that subjects.

Answer (score 4):

very few of those stewart topics belong to algebra as i think of it.  i would suggest learning the "root - factor" theorem, the rational root theorem, and get good at dividing polynomials, and also know the careful statement of the division algorithm.  then i guess you should learn the quadratic theorem.  to me that's pretty much (high school) algebra. as a book i like Harold Jacobs' Elementary Algebra.

Comment: Many thanks! I'm going to look into that!

Comment: for a much more ambitious and thorough book, i like euler's elements of algebra.  it starts at the very beginning but goes quite far. it is avaiulable free online, but i have a print copy from maybe cambridge university press.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to find it, in my country it wasnt even printed, can you believe that?